# A Question Regarding an Accessibility Relation on the Class of All Models of ZFC

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Consider the class of all models of ZFC and consider the following accessibility relation on the class--that each model in the class can know what are the cardinals and ordinals of every other member of the class, what are the sets of ordinals of every other member of the class, and what is the satisfaction relation of every other member of the class (it is a given that this accessibility relation is reflexive and it is also a given that beings within each model can communicate with beings in every other model in the class).  Certainly the class of all models of ZFC with this accessibility relation forms a type of 'multiverse' (by definition of the accessibility relation, this class with this type of accessibility relation will form the semantics of the modal logic S5 and should satisfy some sort of maximal principle).  What would this maximal principle be and what happens to forcing within this 'multiverse'--in particular, what happens to cardinal collapse within this 'multiverse' (i.e. can cardinal collapse occur within this type of 'multiverse')?

Comment: There are more than several definitions of a multiverse. Could you be slightly more explicit, or give an exact reference to the definition you draw from?

Comment: The papers I am considering are Hamkins' and Lowe's papers on the modal logic of forcing ( I am trying to generalize the modal semantics of ZFC to include all models of ZFC, not just the forcing extensions), Hamkins' and Yang's paper "Satisfaction is not absolute" (see page 3 of that paper--they claim that if each model of set theory has access to the satisfaction relation of every other model of ZFC, satisfaction is absolute).  Finally, I am referring to your comment in your answer to my last question, i.e. "the 'L--people' don't know what is beyond their universe" (they now do...).

Comment: Does this help at all?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by a proper class "knowing the satisfaction relation of a proper class"?

Comment: @Andres:  I will give you a direct quote from pg. 3 of "Satisfaction is not absolute", "...the slogan [Satisfaction is absolute--my comment] is true to a very high degree whenever...between any two models of set theory...one...has access to the satisfaction relation of the other...since any model of set theory that can see two satisfaction relations for a structure will see by induction on formulas that they must agree."   I asked Prof. Hamkins whether the term "access" in that quote referred to the access relation found in modal semantics (I just checked my email) and no answer

Comment: has been forthcoming.  Since the access relation I defined on the class of all models of ZFC allows a model of ZFC to 'see' the cardinals, ordinals ,and satisfaction relation of any other model of ZFC, by the above quote, the satisfaction relation defined on the proper class of all models of ZFC must be absolute, so the results discovered by Hamkins and Yang in their paper will not arise.  I hope this helps.

Comment: By way of clarification, Victoria Gitman and Joel David Hamkins in their paper "A Natural Model of The Multiverse Axioms" (arXiv: mathLO/1104.4450) define a multiverse as a "a nonempty collection of models of ZFC". That seems as good a definition as any....

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, I'm glad to hear that you're reading my papers. Let me try to answer your question, which I've just noticed.

The first thing to say is that you don't seem to be using the accessibility concept as it is normally understood. A [Kripke model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) consists of a collection of possible worlds, each with its own truths in the underlying (nonmodal) language, and a relation between the worlds called the *accessibility* relation. Thus, we say that one world $u$ in such a Kripke model *accesses* another world $v$, if $u$ is related to $v$ under this accessibility relation. The accessibility relation is then used to define the truth condition for modal assertions at each world. Namely, the assertion $\diamond\varphi$ is true at a world $u$, just in case $\varphi$ is true at some world $v$ that $u$ can access. So the worlds of the Kripke model become a directed graph under the accessibility relation, and the nature of this directed graph often determines the modal theory. For example, when the digraph is a partial order, then you'll get S4 being true at every world, and if it is reflexive, transitive and symmetric (i.e. an equivalence relation), then you get S5 being true at every world.

But the accessibility relation you mention in your question is not like this, since it is not a relation between worlds. Rather, you seem to have in mind some kind of relation that allows one model of set theory to see inside another model and inspect the nature of its ordinals,  cardinals and sets of ordinals. But if it is allowed to undertake constructions with the knowledge it gains from such kind of inspections, and form new sets using those predicates, then this will definitely violate ZFC. For example, no model will be able to satisfy the power set axiom, since there will always be some other world with a new subset added by forcing, and with the kind of access you seem to mention, the new set would have to have been there already, violating power set.

So your construction does not seem to be set-up for the maximality principle, without further explanation about what you meant.

Comment: @Prof. Hamkins: Very interesting observation in your second paragraph.  As for the first paragraph in your answer, I have a couple of questions, just for clarification.  First, as you and Gitman defined a 'Multiverse' as (since one is talking about the set-theoretic multiverse) "nonempty collection of models of ZFC", is it wrong to deem each model of ZFC in that collection a 'possible world'?  If it isn't, then certainly the pair ($\mathcal M$, R) where R is the accessibility relation a Kripke Frame?  Since R is an arbitrary binary relation on $\mathcal M$, is it not legitimate

Comment: to interpret R in such a manner as to define how one model of ZFC in $\mathcal M$ has access to another?  That is what I attempted to do in my question.  Now it may be so that that particular interpretation of R will not allow any model of ZFC in $\mathcal M$ to satisfy the power set axiom but that is a problem with the interpretation of R (it is this problem with the interpretation of R that I find interesting).  I guess the next question to ask would be:  what would be a ZFC-preserving interpretation of R on $\mathcal M$ be?

Comment: Also regarding your comment "no model will be able to satisfy the power set axiom, since there will be some other world with a new subset added by forcing, and with the kind of access you seem to mention, the new set would have to have been there already, violating power set", given a model M and its forcing extension M[G] in $\mathcal M$ where M[G] adds the new sets in question, could those new sets be deemed proper classes relative to M but still be definable as proper classes in M?  That may be nonsense, so please let me know either way--if I'm not underdstanding....

Comment: Yes, Gitman and I consider various collections of models of ZFC as different toy multiverses for the purpose of proving the theorem in that paper, and in this context, yes, each model of ZFC should be thought of as a possible world in that multiverse. As for your relation $R$, however, my objection was that you don't seem to have a binary relation on these worlds. What you need to do is to define when $u\mathrel{R} v$ holds. You can't say that $u$ can access something inside $v$, but only that $u\mathrel{R}v$ holds, or that it doesn't hold. If $u\mathrel{R} v$ always holds, then this is ...

Comment: ...an equivalence relation, and you'll get the modal theory S5 being valid. If you say that $u\mathrel{R} v$ holds just in case $u$ and $v$ have the same ordinals, then this also is an equivalence relation, and you'll get S5 again. The forcing accessibility relation is defined so that $u\mathrel{R} v$ just in case $v$ is a forcing extension of $u$, and Benedikt and I proved that the provable validities here are S4.2.

Comment: @ Prof Hamkins:  Suppose for any u,v $\in$ $\mathcal M$, u$\mathrel R$ v just in case u,v have the same ordinals, cardinals, and cofinalities.  Furthermore, let such u,v be the only models of ZFC allowed in $\mathcal M$.  According to your examples, the modal theory S5 is valid for such an $\mathcal M$.  Is there a maximal principle related to this particular    $\mathcal M$?

Comment: Yes, that Kripke model will satisfy S5, since the accessibility relation is reflexive, transitive and symmetric. And S5 itself can be viewed as a maximality principle, since it is equivalent over S4 to the axiom $\Diamond\Box\varphi\implies\varphi$.

Comment: @Prof. Hamkins: Thanks.  Another question:  Can cardinal collapse be defined over this particular $\mathcal M$? If so, in what way?